# memcpy third argument is bigger than real size of second argument

Tags: memcpy

Here is problem code:

```
int* m_A = new int[4]
int* reAlloc = new int[10];
memcpy(reAlloc, m_A, 10 *sizeof(int));
```

When I've compiled it seems okay.

Is it okay when the third argument of `memcpy` is greater than the size of 
second argument of `memcpy`?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** okay. Your code does not ensure that `m_A` points to a memory location which is at least `10 * sizeof(int)` from `reAlloc`, so the areas might overlap. That means your code causes *undefined behavior*.

Even if you tried to fix it using [`memmove()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove), you are still in the grey zone, because you don't know what is at `*(m_A + 9)`.

Might be your data, then it would work (with `memmove()`, because it still might be `reAlloc`'s data). Might not be your data, in which case you'll get some SIGSEGV.

`memcpy()` and `memmove()` are low-level memory manipulation functions, the compiler will expect you know what you are doing and will not emit warnings.

Comment: hmm.. okay i understand then is there any solution to this??? any other operation???

Comment: Well, no. If you have 4 integers, why would you want to copy 10? What do you expect to have in the `reAlloc` array after the operation? Try to describe what you want to do.